# Flat and dark colors in VirtualBox Win7 guest in fullscreen mode only

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, colors

I'm using VirtualBox 5.1.10 on a Ubuntu 16 host machine with a Nvidia GTX 970 and the proprietary drivers. The guest system is Windows 7 Pro 64bit. The only purpose of this VM is to run Adobe Lightroom 6, which unfortunately does not run natively or with wine.

The problem is this: when I start the virtual machine in a normal or maximized windows (not fullscreen), the colors within the windows guest are bright and have a nice contrast, just like in the host system. But when I press LeftCTRL-F and enter the fullscreen mode, the colors instantly get noticeably darker and much flatter (or kind of more greyish). This would be totally acceptable for any other purpose other than photo editing, as you can imagine.

When I press LeftCTRL-F again to switch back to windowed mode, the colors also go back to "wonderful" instantly. Did anyone run into this issue before?

Update: Just to be clear, the whole windows guest's colors are different in fullscreen mode, not just within Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows 10. I eventually found that it can be corrected by disabling the menu bar.

Go to the Settings for your VM, then User Interface, and uncheck "Mini ToolBar: Show in Full-screen/Seamless".

Comment: Odd enough: I can confirm the bug & the solution under virtual box 5.2.40, Linux guest, Linux host.